# complex plane questions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find where the points of the complex plane are if,

a) $|\pi - \arg z| < \pi/4$

b) $|\Re z| < 1$

c) $\Im \left(\frac{z+1}{z+i}\right) = 0$

d) $z = z_1 + t(\cos x + i\sin x), 0\leq x\leq=\pi/4$ where $z_1 = 1+2i$ and $t=2$

Please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Your part c) has no relation. What does it mean?

Comment: Hi Rory, just edited the question. Sorry, forgot to put 0 at the other end of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

a) This says the angle for $z$ is between $\frac {3\pi}4$ and $\frac {5\pi}4$.

[image]

At least, this is the answer if you are using the generalized arg function, which can give any real answer, especially allowing values between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. If you are using the principal value function Arg, that would limit the angle to between $\frac {3\pi}4$ and $\pi$ and would lose the part of my graph in the third quadrant (negative real and imaginary parts).

[image]

b) This says the real part is between $-1$ and $1$.

[image]

d) This is a circular arc, centered at $1+2i$ with radius $2$ and angle from $0$ to $\pi/4$.

[image]

c) If we let $z=x+yi$ for real $x$ and $y$, this makes
$$0=\Im\left(\frac{z+1}{z+i}\right)$$
$$=\Im\left(\frac{x+yi+1}{x+yi+i}\right)$$
$$=\Im\left(\frac{(x+yi+1)(x-yi-i)}{(x+yi+i)(x-yi-i)}\right)$$
$$=\Im\left(\frac{x^2-xyi-xi+xyi+y^2+y+x-yi-i}{x^2+(y+1)^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{-x-y-1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}$$
$$0=-x-y-1$$
$$y=-x-1$$

The original expression prohibits $z=-i$, so we put an open dot on that point of the graph.

[image]

Comment: What program are you using to draw these pictures?

Comment: @David: [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/). I am using equations in $x$ and $y$ and geometric objects, rather than complex numbers, in the definitions of the graphics.